# How can I detect hidden images in file?

Tags: bash, image, file

I'm trying to write a bash script that, given a file in this form, detects that in this file there is an hidden image:

```
[random data][image file][random data]
```

My first approach is to search with grep for

```
[random data][image header][random data][image footer][random data]
```

in the file, but I can't found a table with all headers and footers of all image file formats. Does someone have this table, or can you suggest another way to proceed?

Comment: What you are talking about is "magic numbers". These are the file specific hex codes. The good start point for you may be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures. All the best.

Comment: You are looking for a forensic tool. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19483559/2834978) and the accepted one could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested, I found this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Given a file as argument, scan for hidden images in file.
# written by Cosimo Colaci


#   Hex signature       File format
#
#   47 49 46 38 37 61   gif
#   47 49 46 38 39 61   gif
#   FF D8 FF DB         jpeg
#   FF D8 FF E0         jpg
#   4A 46 49 46 00 01   jpeg
#   89 50 4E 47 0D 0A   png
#   1A 0A               png
#   42 4D               bmp
# etc...

# Declarations
E_NOFILE=66
E_NOREAD=67


# Check filename
filename="$1"

if [ ! -f "$filename" ]
then
  echo "Error! No such file!"
  exit $E_NOFILE
fi

if [ ! -r "$filename" ]
then
  echo "Unable to read \"$filename\"."
  exit $E_NOREAD
fi


# Scan file for hidden image
cat "$filename" | grep '47\\49\\46\\38\\37\\61' 1>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo
  echo "Warning: a GIF may be hidden in $filename."
  echo
  exit 0
fi

cat "$filename" | grep '47\\49\\46\\38\\39\\61' 1>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo
  echo "Warning: a GIF may be hidden in $filename."
  echo
  exit 0
fi

cat "$filename" | grep 'FF\\D8\\FF\\DB' 1>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo
  echo "Warning: a JPEG may be hidden in $filename."
  echo
  exit 0
fi

cat "$filename" | grep 'FF\\D8\\FF\\E0' 1>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo
  echo "Warning: a JPG may be hidden in $filename."
  echo
  exit 0
fi

cat "$filename" | grep '4A\\46\\49\\46\\00\\01' 1>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo
  echo "Warning: a JPEG may be hidden in $filename."
  echo
  exit 0
fi

cat "$filename" | grep '89\\50\\4E\\47\\0D\\0A' 1>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo
  echo "Warning: a PNG may be hidden in $filename."
  echo
  exit 0
fi

cat "$filename" | grep '1A\\0A' 1>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo
  echo "Warning: a PNG may be hidden in $filename."
  echo
  exit 0
fi

cat "$filename" | grep '42\\4D' 1>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo
  echo "Warning: a BMP may be hidden in $filename."
  echo
  exit 0
fi

# etc. etc....


# If nothing found...
echo "$filename: File seems OK."
exit 0

# To scan all regular files nested in /some/directory:
# find /some/directory -type f -exec /home/cosimo/Università/Sistemi\ Operativi/scripts/esame99.sh {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using forensic tools as Luis suggested.
In the past, I personally found [binwalk](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk) appropriate to detect and split files all joined into one in sequence from linux shell.